# Open method in ajax call not responding

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to JSON and AJAX,
SO i tried this piece of code to get JSON data from the url mentioned and then using a AJAX call i tried to print it on console, however nothing gets printed on the console.

Please someone correct what is it that i am doing wrong here, below is the code snippet.

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var display = document.getElementById("display");
req.open("GET", "http://www.filltext.com/?rows=10&id={index}&email={email}&username={username}&password={randomString|5}&pretty=true", true);
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var res = req.responseText;
  Console.log(res);
};
});
req.send();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<Button id= 'btn'>click me</Button>
<div id = 'display'></div>

<script>"Test.js"</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are only adding the "response event handler" after clicking the button. By that time the Ajax request might already have finished. Bind the handler *before* you are sending the request.

Comment: JavaScript is **case sensitive**. It's `console` not `Console`.

Comment: Make sure the you are able to make the AJAX call to the remote domain. Might be blocked due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Check your console.

Answer (score 0):

When you set req.onreadystatechange inside btn event you only add the callback to request. The problem is the request has already been made. You need to make request on btn click, then you call send() inside the btn action.

**console** instead of **Console**

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var display = document.getElementById("display");

req.open("GET", "http://www.filltext.com/?rows=10&id={index}&email={email}&username={username}&password={randomString|5}&pretty=true", true);
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var res = req.responseText;
    console.log(res);
};

btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    req.send();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<Button id= 'btn'>click me</Button>
<div id = 'display'></div>

<script>"Test.js"</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your JS code and put everything inside the block, so it looks nice :)

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var display = document.getElementById("display");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "http://www.filltext.com/?rows=10&id={index}&email={email}&username={username}&password={randomString|5}&pretty=true", true);
    req.send();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var res = req.responseText;
        console.log(res);
    };
});
```

Comment: The irony of "so it looks nice" and then your code is badly indented - not nice!

Comment: It might be nice to actually tell the OP why this fixes the problem - its certainly not fixed by making it look nice!